# Object [object Object] has no method 'highcharts'

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I included highcharts.js and jquery but I kept getting this error.

I am using MVC4. I downloaded highcharts lib from their website and included the files into the "Scripts" folder

my html look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

    <!-- highcharts -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>

    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

And the content of body:

```
<script> $(function () {
     $('#container').highcharts({
         ...
     });
 });</script>

<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are including jQuery twice:
first in a script tag and then in the body `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`

Try removing `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` and it will work

The second include wipes out all plugins that you included before it.